# how convert big array having some sequences into another array containing those sequences as an array element?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array having multiple values e.g.

```
array[] = {1,2,3,11,12,13,4,5,14,15,16,,6,7,21,22,8,9,23}
```

I want to convert it into smaller arrays like:

```
array1[] = {{11,12,13},{14,15,16},{21,22},{23}}
```

i.e. having an array element which is greater than 10 regularly from one smaller array.

Comment: Please post your attempt- the code you wrote to try this yourself. Generally in Stackoverflow people wont respond to directly providing the whole solution. please see.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: actually I didn't even know how I can implement this

Comment: What are the rules? the sub arrays seem random

Comment: Why `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` are not used for generating the output?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just loop it. But I'm sure it's possible to think of something smarter.

```
public int[][] Split(int[] input, int threshold)
{
    var output = new List<int[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        var subArray = new List<int>();

        while (i < input.Length && input[i] > threshold)
        {
            subArray.Add(input[i++]);
        }

        if (subArray.Any())
        {
            output.Add(subArray.ToArray());
        }
    }

    return output.ToArray();
}
```

And then use it:

```
var input = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 4, 5, 14, 15, 16, 6, 7, 21, 22, 8, 9, 23 };

var output = Split(input, 10); // {{11,12,13},{14,15,16},{21,22},{23}}
```